# How to display a network with better separation using the Networkx package?

Tags: python, plot, graph, networkx, graph-layout

I created a graph object using the `pytextrank` package like so:

```
import pytextrank
### ........................... 
### Some steps and calculations
### ...........................
graph, ranks = pytextrank.text_rank(path_stage1)
```

And I can use the `networkx` package to make a `networkx` drawing like so:

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(50,50))
nx.draw(graph, with_labels=True) 

plt.show()
```

[image]

But as you can see, the words are mostly concentrated around the center. I would like to see higher separation between classes of words. How do I do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you are looking for is a different [**layout**](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/reference/drawing.html#module-networkx.drawing.layout) (Networkx's term for node positioning algorithms that are used when drawing graphs). By default, `nx.draw()` is using spring layout. Changing your layout can be done as follows:

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(50,50))
pos = nx.spectral_layout(graph)
nx.draw(graph, pos=pos, with_labels=True) 

plt.show()
```

You can play with a few layouts to find one that suits your needs.

Another option is to save your graph to a file, and load it with [gephi](https://gephi.org/), which has a nice GUI for visualizing and exploring your graph. (Also supporting several graph layout algorithms).